How can I make ASP.NET Core bind a CSV from query string to a class-level property that is a list of string?
I have this query in my URL:
example.com/cars?brands=bmw,toyota

I also have this property in my CarController:
[BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
public List<string> Brands { get; set; }

But what I get is a list with a single item in it that is bmw,toyota.
How can I tell configure ASP.NET Core to parse the CSV automatically?

you could make a custom model binder but wouldn't it be much easier to just parse the comma delimited query string, or change it to a post and pass in an array of strings?

You can handle comma-separated strings and convert them into a property of type List by implementing a custom model binder.
Create a custom model binder:
public class CsvListModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // Get the value from the ValueProvider
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Get the raw value (comma-separated string)
        var rawValue = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawValue))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(new List<string>());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Split the raw value into an array of strings
        var splitValues = rawValue.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Create a List<string> from the split values
        var model = new List<string>(splitValues);

        // Set the ModelBindingResult to successful with the model
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Then create a model binder provider:
public class CsvListModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(List<string>))
        {
            return new CsvListModelBinder();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

Then register this custom model binder provider:
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CsvListModelBinderProvider());
});

Test:


Should I change my code? Or would it suffice to register it?

Yes, you just need to register the custom model binder provider. The execution timing of a custom model binder provider occurs during the model binding process. So, when you send a request including data that needs to be bound, before performing specific model bindings, ASP.NET Core queries the registered model binder providers to determine if there is a suitable model binder for the target type. If there is, then it will parse the CSV automatically.
